# How to operate on an ArrayList of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm facing a problem when operating on an ArrayList of ArrayList in Java. I have this thing in my code-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> L1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Problem is, I have no idea as to how I should operate on this (addition, removal, traversal etc.). I wish to create an adjacency list (for implementing simple, undirected graphs), and my instructor suggests that I should create an ArrayList of ArrayList. I know I can do the following to add new element-

```
L1.add(//Something I want to add);
```

But this throws up an error in the current case for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArrayList` of an `ArrayList`, just think that the outer object is an `ArrayList` and you are done.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list2d = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
// add an element to the list
list2d.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
// retrieve a list 
ArrayList<Integer> list1d = list2d.get(0);
// add an integer
list2d.get(0).add(123);
```

By the way, an adjacency list is just a list of edges, there's no need to store them for each vertex, especially if the graph is undirected. A list of `Edge` would be enough:

```
class Edge {
  Vertex v1, v2;
}

ArrayList<Edge> adjacencyList;
```

If you want to store them on a per vertex basis then you could avoid using a list of lists by encapsulating the edges inside the vertex class itself but this will require twice the edges:

```
class Vertex {
  int value;
  ArrayList<Vertex> adjacency;
}
```

but which one is best depends on what kind of operation you need to perform on the graph. For a small graph there is no practical difference.

Another possible implementation, if you just need to know if two vertex are connected:

```
class Edge {
  public final int v1, v2;

  public boolean equals(Object o) { return o != null && o instanceof Edge && o.hashCode() == hashCode(); }

  public int hashCode() { return v1 ^ v2; } // simple hash code, could be more sophisticated
}

Set<Edge> adjacencyList = new HashSet<Edge>();
```

Comment: This might be misleading. By adjacencyList, it might be also meant a list of neighbour vertices (their indices) of certain vertex, thus L1.get(i) will return list of all vertex indices neighboring with index with idx i.

Comment: The advancement of per vertex lists of edges is getting all neigbours n of the vertex v in O(n(v)) time where n(v) is the number of neighbours of v. If only edges are stored, it will require O(e) time where e is the number of edges in the graph. The difference could be critical in some applications.

Comment: @kenor: in a context in which such a difference would be critical you won't be using an `ArrayList` at all, you would use sets for adjacency lists inside vertices in any case. There's no need to have an O(n) lookup when you can have O(1) if performance is critical.

Comment: of course, that was more of a hypothetical note, since the asker was for some reason instructed to use list of lists

Answer (score 1):

Try `L1.get(i).add(whatever);`, and of course first check whether `L1.get(i)` exists, otherwise add that inner list first.

It's something like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> L1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); //better use interfaces

List<Integer> first = null;
if( L1.size() > 0) {
 first = L1.get(0); //first element
}
else {
  first = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  L1.add(first);      
}

first.add(4711); //or whatever you like to add
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

will create a new List within the first list. Then you can

```
L1.get(0).add(5)
```

Comment: Yep, sorry, no IDE :X

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Integer>> L1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();    
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(4);
list1.add(5);
```

//add list to the list

```
L1.add(list1);
```

iterate over the list of lists

```
for( List<Integer> list: L1 ){
      for(Integer i:list){
          System.out.println(i);
      }
}
```

Comment: `L1.add(list1);` would not work unless L1 is defined to be `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only add objects of type ArrayList to L1. So you could do this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> firstList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
secondList.add(0);

firstList.add(secondList);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a new element to the outer array:

```
ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
L1.add(inner);
```

Then to add element to the inner array:

```
   int exampleInt = 10;
   ArrayList<Integer> inner = L1.get(0);
   inner.add(exampleInt);
```

To traverse all elements in all arrays:

```
   for (ArrayList<Integer> inner : L1)
   {
      for (Integer element : inner)
      {
         System.out.println(element);
      }
   }
```